# Swift: How to save screenshot of a view with all views which below that view?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, calayer, screen-capture

I need to make a screenshot of tableview(it has a clear background). But under it, I have one ImageView and blur view as well. I need to get screenshot with all those views.

I tried different solutions, but they did not capture the bottom views. Any ways to do that?

Also, I do not need a full screenshot of the screen. Only bounds which are limited by tableView. I guess, I had some option how to make a full screenshot, but it did not work with view

I tried:

1:

```
  func snapshot(of rect: CGRect? = nil) -> UIImage? {
    // snapshot entire view

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, isOpaque, 0)
    drawHierarchy(in: bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    let wholeImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    // if no `rect` provided, return image of whole view

    guard let image = wholeImage, let rect = rect else { return wholeImage }

    // otherwise, grab specified `rect` of image

    let scale = image.scale
    let scaledRect = CGRect(x: rect.origin.x * scale, y: rect.origin.y * scale, width: rect.size.width * scale, height: rect.size.height * scale)
    guard let cgImage = image.cgImage?.cropping(to: scaledRect) else { return nil }
    return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage, scale: scale, orientation: .up)
}
```

2:

```
             UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(tableView.frame.size)
             tableView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
             let image1 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
             UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

My hierarchy is:

- base UIView

  - UIImageView with image

    - UIBlurEffect

      - UITableView with clear background which displays chart

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the screen so we can better understand the problem?

Comment: You should put all those views on new uiview and take screenshot of this view. It will look like this UIViewController - NewView - (all views which you need)

Comment: Also, can you post something more - like code - because we really have no clue what *"different solutions"* you've tried?

Comment: @Jeremy Sh I updated my question.

Comment: its hard to picture what you want to do without a screenshot

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question, you want a true screen shot but not of the entire screen. Therefore, take a raw screenshot:

```
let snap = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.snapshotView(afterScreenUpdates: true)
snap.frame = view.bounds // or something, if necessary
```

Apply a mask to the screenshot with a frame equal to the bounds of the table view:

```
let mask = CALayer()
mask.frame = tableView.frame.bounds
mask.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
snap.layer.mask = mask
```

Comment: The top two lines are all I was looking for, thanks :)